# I Want To Use UIRotationGestureRecognizer for to move arrow on same center..?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

> HELLO Friends,
>    i Want to Use UIRotationGestureRecognizer for t0 rotate arrow on the rigid center
>
> Is It Possible to Use The UIRotationGestureRecognizer only With one one touch